# Linking Django-oscar to native IOS app for shopping

Tags: ios, swift, e-commerce, tastypie, django-oscar

Currently i am using `django-oscar` as my self hosted ecommerce solution to allow for merchants to have standard abilities such as uploading products, inventory management, etc.. on the backend.

The marketplace however will be on our native IOS app (currently live). We are thinking of using django-tastypie to create the API and transfer data back and forth from the admin to marketplace(on the app).

A few questions i have:

1. How would we go about creating the checkout process, shopping carts and etc? Hosted ecommerce solutions such as Shopify have IOS SDKs to handle shopping carts checkout and etc on the IOS side of things but `django-oscar` from what I see doesn't have such SDK.
2. How would even sending the information back to the admin dashboard(from the IOS app) to update our merchants orders, inventory management, etc work? `django-oscar` only seems to cover how to do so with web based apps but not with a native IOS app.

Nothing around the web seems to explain this particular scenario at all, and I was hoping someone in the development community could lend some insight into this arena, and connect the dots.

*we are using swift for our IOS app

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend checking out [Django oscar API](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar-api), I think it does exactly what you need!

Answer (score 0):

creating api is the way to do it. django-oscar is having schema for cart that can be reused. With django rest framework, we can easily write the apis for add to cart, delete from cart etc. I would recommend django rest framework (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) instead of django-tastypie. django rest framework is easily understandable for a django developer, because it is more django like than tastypie. rest framework has web browsable api as well.